# Trouble producing a polygon on top of a scatterplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon

Currently, I am trying to transition my graphical knowledge from the `plot` function in R, to the `ggplot` function. I have began constructing scatterplots and corresponding legends for a given data set, however I want to incorporate the function `geom_polygon` onto my plots using `ggplot`.

Specifically, I want to capture a triangular region from the origin of a scatterplot. For reproducibility, say I have the following data set:

```
rawdata<-data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,
                         2,1,-1,
                         3,-1,-1,
                         4,-1,1,
                         4,-2,2),5,3,byrow=TRUE))
names(rawdata)<-c("Town","x.coordinate","y.coordinate")
rawdata[,1]<-as.factor(rawdata[,1])
```

To construct a scatterplot along with a legend, I have been told to do the following:

```
p1<-ggplot(data=rawdata,aes(x=x.coordinate,y=y.coordinate,colour=Town,shape=Town)) 
+ theme_bw() + geom_point()
```

The result is the following:
[Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYG9f.png)

What I want to do now is produce a polygon. To do so, I have construct the following dataframe to use in the `geom_polygon` function:

```
geom_polygon(data=polygondata,aes(x = xa, y = ya),colour="darkslategray2",
             fill = "darkslategray2",alpha=0.25)
```

However, when I combine this with `p1`, I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Town' not found
```

From some messing around, I have noticed that when I omit the `shape` argument from the `ggplot` function, I can easily produce the desired output which is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOn37.png). However, I wish to **keep the shape for aesthetics**.

I also get a similar problem when I try to produce arrows which connect points on the scatterplot using `ggplot`. However, I will address this problem after, as the root problem may be here.

Comment: "I have noticed that when I omit the shape argument from the ggplot function, I can easily produce the desired output" - isn't this the answer to your question?

Comment: Indeed it is an answer, however, I wish to keep the `shape` argument for aesthetics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to `polygondata`:

```
polygondata$Town = NA
```

Even though you're not using that variable in `geom_polygon`, ggplot expects it to be there if that column is used for an aesthetic in the main call to ggplot.

Alternatively, I think you could avoid the error if you move the aesthetic mapping in the initial plot to `geom_point` rather than the main ggplot call, like this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=rawdata) + 
        theme_bw() + 
        geom_point(aes(x=x.coordinate, y=y.coordinate, colour=Town, shape=Town))
```

In that case, you wouldn't need to add a `Town` column to `polygondata`.